# FormData removes duplicate elements

Tags: javascript, html, forms, form-data

I have multiple inputs of the form `<input type="hidden" name="currentMembers[]" value="joe">` which share the same name (I have also tried `name="currentMembers"`). I then make a `FormData` object using `var form = new FormData(document.querySelector('#modalForm'));` however when I print `console.log(form.get("currentMembers"));` I only get the last element of currentMembers, and not all of them. How do I make it so it will include all elements of the same name?

Comment: Provided the name ends with a `[]` the actual form data includes all values.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `form.getAll("currentMemebers[]")` to get all the values

```js
var form = new FormData(document.querySelector('#modalForm'));
console.log(form.getAll("currentMembers[]"));
```

```html
<form id="modalForm">
  <input type="hidden" name="currentMembers[]" value="joe">
  <input type="hidden" name="currentMembers[]" value="joe2">
  <input type="hidden" name="currentMembers[]" value="joe3">
 </form>
```